# Как перевести padding из % в px?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Делаю функцию анимации стилей, столкнулся с проблемой перевода единиц измерения.
Предположим мне нужно анимировать `padding`. У элемента он такой `padding: 20%;` А пользователь хочет изменить его на `padding: 10px;`. Следовательно мне нужно узнать сколько 20% будет в "px" и работать с этим значением. Я знаю что `padding` берет процент от ширины родителя. Но если у родителя тоже указан padding (и тоже в %), как узнать content width ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getComputedStyle()` вам в помощь.

```js
alert(
  window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myDiv"), null).paddingLeft
);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" style="width:50px%; height:50px; padding-left:20%"></div>
```

Comment: Я с просонья прочел не padding, а width. Поэтому в начале советовал getBoundingClientRect :)

Answer (score 1):

Используй css transition:

```js
document.getElementById("apply-padding").addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById("dest").style.padding = document.getElementById("padding").value;
});
```

```css
p {
  padding: 20%;
  background: silver;
  transition: padding 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<input type=text id=padding value=20%>
<button id=apply-padding>Apply</button>

<p id=dest>Some text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery

```
$('#my_el').css('padding-top');
```

вернет значение в px, в независимости что указано в css.
При присвоении установит значение в любой нужной единице измерения

```
$('#my_el').css('padding-top','10%');
```

если нужно узнать ширину блока с отступами

```
$('#my_el').outerWidth(true);
```

посмотреть свойства родителя

```
$('#my_el').parent().css('padding-top');
```